# Is this use of "that" incorrect?

Tags: word-usage, relative-pronouns, free-relative-clauses

I proofreaded an essay and this sentence

## 1

> Obviously, you don't need to worry about *the shipping fees **that*** I'll
>    be more than happy to pay to make up the damage I did to you.

was corrected to

## 2

> Obviously, you don't need to worry about *the shipping fees **as*** I'll
>    be more than happy to pay to make up the damage I did to you.

I think it is like having

> You don't need to worry about the shipping fees.
>
> I'll be more than happy to pay the shipping fees.

and putting the two clauses together:

> You don't need to worry about the shipping fees that I'll be more than happy to pay

Comment: The former sentence is correct. Version 2 sounds incorrect to my non-native ear. It's a that clause. Obviously, you don't need to worry about *the shipping fees* **that** *I'll be more than happy to pay* to make up the damage I did to you.

Comment: Changing it to a causal "as" clause (as in #2) changes the meaning slightly, but is probably fine because the "as" meaning is implicit. If I had been the proofreader, I would have suggested making it 2 sentences because the "that" clause is made up of two bits itself, which makes it difficult to read. I would suggest: **"Obviously, you don't need to worry about the shipping fees. I'll be more than happy to pay them to make up the damage I did to you."**

Comment: @SovereignSun The "as" means the same thing as "because". It's perfectly fine. If I were proofreading 2, I'd probably recommend adding the word "them" after "to pay" to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, sentence 1) refers to a subset of the fees, those that you are willing to pay. The sentence doesn't guarantee that you agree to all of them. If you told me

> "You don't need to worry about rain coming in the windows that I decided to close,"

I would be justified in worrying about rain coming in one of the other windows.

Your final proposal has the same problem, it uses "that" and thus only refers to a subset of the fees. Of course that subset may be all of them, but I assume that your intention is to reassure the other person by guaranteeing that you will pay **all** of the fees.

Sentence 2) establishes a causal link, the other person doesn't have to worry at all **because** you agree to pay.